# ModelMapper Condition On Non-Deepest Property (With java.util.Optional)

Tags: java, option-type, object-object-mapping, modelmapper

Given this simplification of my structure:

```
public class Order
{
    public String firstName;
    public Optional<PaymentInfo> paymentInfo;
}

public class PaymentInfo
{
    public String billingAddress;
    public int totalAmount;
}
```

I want to map to this class:

```
public class SimpleOrder
{
    public string firstName;
    public Optional<String> billingAddress;
}
```

I'm not sure how to only map the `billingAddress` if the Optional has value. I was thinking something like this:

```
private static Condition<?, ?> optionalHasValue = 
    (MappingContext<Optional<PaymentInfo>, String> context)
    -> context.getSource().isPresent();

private static class OrderMap extends PropertyMap<Order, SimpleOrder>
{
    @Override
    protected void configure()
    {
        map(source.firstName, destination.firstName);
        when(optionalHasValue)
            .map(source.paymentInfo.get().billingAddress, destination.billingAddress);
    }
}
```

but this fails with error "Cannot map final type java.util.Optional.". I did see [this question about mapping Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28603853/modelmapper-handling-java-8-optionalmyobjectdto-fields-to-optionalmyobject) but it seemed be about a different issue.